# nginx server sometime returns 404 Not Found for valid a URL

Tags: nginx, php

I am using a nginx server with PHP-FPM for web development. While sending continuous AJAX calls from the browser to the server, I sometimes get 404 Not Found errors for a valid URL. (When I open the URL in a new browser tab, it is showing the page properly.)

I am unable to debug why nginx is behaving like this. I don't know if it is dropping connections. What should I do?

I am using default installation of nginx and have not made any changes to it.

This is my nginx.conf

server {

```
    listen                                  IP address with PORT ssl;
    server_name                             SERVER Name;

    root                                    /u01/projectfolder;

    ssl                             on;
    ssl_certificate                 /etc/nginx/ssl/36287365.net.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key             /etc/nginx/ssl/36287365.net.key;



    index                                   index.php index.html;
    log_not_found                           off;
    charset                                 utf-8;

   location /rainbow {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /rainbow/index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9101;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include         fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

I have also added the log at php side index.php but for 404 requests logs are not generated. I guess the request is not reached to php way fastcgi and nginx.

Please help

Comment: Have you checked the nginx and php log?  Are you using fastcgi?

Comment: Not enough info here: What urls? What is your configurations? What are the pages doing behind the scenes?

Comment: Your best bet is to post this question on http://www.serverfault.com Your problems seem to be load related and this requires extended diagnostics.

Comment: Grammatical and formatting

Comment: I have checked the nginx and php logs and using fastcgi

Answer (score 2):

This may happen if you have more than one server listening on the same port, make sure only one PHP server listens on 9101.

I've experienced this with two different Node.js servers running simultaneously, listening to the same port - about 50% of the requests returned HTTP error 404 while the rest did OK 200.

You can verify that it's not Nginx's fault by generating the same request using CURL directly on the machine, bypassing Nginx. If this still occurs, it's not their fault.

Answer (score -1):

If you're under high load or being DDOS attacked, you might ensure the correct error page exists for the corresponding error code that is supposed to be returned. For example:

https://github.com/openresty/openresty/issues/278

...if your 503 error code page is missing, it might return a 404 instead of a 503 to the end user. This is a niche case, but worth mentioning here.